# How does the following scheme function work exactly?

Tags: conditional-statements, scheme

```
(define (evens nums)
  (cond ((empty? nums) ’())
        ((= (remainder (first nums) 2) 0)
         (se (first nums) (evens (bf nums))) )
        (else (evens (bf nums))) ))
```

`se` is an abbreviation for `sentence` & `bf` is an abbreviation for `butfirst`.

I have trouble mainly understanding the special form `cond`.  The first two lines are self explanatory. The third line is returning a boolean but I'm kind of lost on what exactly is the program doing with that result. Is the 4th line just a continuation of the 3th and calling the function recursively whenever the number is even? I'm guessing the 5th line is for the odd numbers but don't really understand it's purpose?

*This must be quite basic for most of you but I'm kind of new to programming.* Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please indent your coffee properly. Currently, it's unreadable

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @NieDzejkob. Let me know If I need to make more changes!

Comment: @ÓscarLópez ```se``` is ```sentence``` & bf is ```butfirst```. This is a modified version of scheme for the CS61A course. Should have mentioned it in the post.

Answer (score 0):

First of all *indent your code properly*.  If you don't do that you don't have a chance of understanding what your programs do.  I have done this for you for your sample.

Secondly without knowing what the `se` and `bf` functions do it's not really possible to know what this code does.

But to answer the question about `cond`.  `cond` forms look like

```
(cond
  (<condition> <form> ...)
  ...
  (else <form> ...))
```

And all `cond` does is evaluate each `<condition>` expression in turn until it finds one that is true, or until it reaches one which is `else`, and, once it has found one it evaluates all the `<form> ...` after it, returning the value(s) of the last form.

All `cond` is is a multiway `if-then-elsif-then-elsif-then-else` expression in other words.

Once you understand that, and format the code properly, and if you know what the `se` and `bf` functions do, then it's possible to sit down and trace through what the function does (start with a list with not very many elements in it!)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestions.This makes a lot of sense now. Line 4 is executed if line 3 is true. Line 5, like I thought, is for when odd number is executed.It goes to the next set of numbers leaving the odd number using the ```butfirst``` .